# insert text to file - bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am exploring sed function(I am aware that I had asked a similar question like this before, but given the fact that I am terribly bad at regex , I need lots of help, but that doesn't mean I didn't try out myself)

what I have here is a simple text file shown below

Id,fruit name and quantity.

this time I want to add the price of the fruit behind the quantity of each fruit respectively **BY FINDING THE FRUIT NAME**.

fruit.txt

```
1,apple,50
2,banana,40
```

I tried this command

```
sed -i -r "s/(apple.*)([,0-9]*)/\1,5/" "fruit.txt"
```

so on the first input

```
 sed -i -r "s/(apple.*)([,0-9]*)/\1,5/" "fruit.txt"
```

my textfile(clothes.txt) will become like this

```
1,apple,50,5
2,banana,40
```

on the second input

```
 sed -i -r "s/(apple.*)([,0-9]*)/\1,30/" "fruit.txt"
```

my textfile(clothes.txt) will become like this

```
1,apple,50,5,30
2,banana,40
```

how do I make it to become like this.

expected output

first input of sed command

my textfile(fruit.txt) will become like this

```
1,apple,50,5
2,banana,40
```

on the second input of sed command

my textfile(fruit.txt) will become like this

```
1,apple,50,30
2,banana,40
```

Comment: Do you have to use sed? Awk would be so much easier (`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$2=="apple"{$4=5}1'`

Comment: I am exploring sed. will be moving to awk after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saying `[,0-9]*`, ensure that you match only one `,`.  You can say:

```
sed -i -r 's/(apple,[^,]*).*/\1,15/' filename
```

Here saying `(apple,[^,]*)` would put `apple` followed by a `,` followed by anything that is *not* a `,` into a group.  The `.*` would match everything remaining.

This would change

```
1,apple,50,5
2,banana,40
```

to

```
1,apple,50,15
2,banana,40
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sed -i -r "s/(apple,[0-9]*).*/\1,30/" "fruit.txt"
```

Here, `\1` is a backreferences. It matches the first capture group.

Before, your first capture group was matching too much.